# Is there anything like an absolutely divergent series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

We all know there exists absolutely convergent series: it is one where it does not matter what the order of the series is upon summation of the infinite series.

I was wondering if there was some kind of **similar property for when we assign values to divergent sums** such that it does not matter which order we sum the terms in.

### Questions

Do "absolutely divergent series" (series which whose value assigned does not matter on the ordering) exist? Is there any quick method to identify such divergent series?

Comment: Um... surely $1 + 2 + 3 +4 +.....$?  Or $1 + 1/2 + 1/3 + 1/4 + ....$?  Or $1 + 1  + 1 + 1+.....$?

Comment: Is there a quick method to identify such a series?

Comment: How do you mean assign values to divergent series?

Comment: @kingW3 .. through analytic continuation or regularization

Comment: @AnantSaxena Consider adding this information into the question as to what you meant by assigning value.

Comment: you need a bigger definition of divergence : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w-I6XTVZXww

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing the point of analytic continuation. Analytic continuation of a series doesn't have anything to do with the series i.e you're not **changing the order of terms** or manipulating the series in any way.

What you're actually doing is finding an analytic function which agrees with the given series where it converges but is also defined somewhere where the series diverges.

I've copied the stuff below the line from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_continuation)

---

If $f$ is an analytic function on a non-empty open subset $U$ of $\Bbb{C}$ then analytic continuations are unique in the following sense: if $V$ is the connected domain of two analytic functions $F_1$ and $F_2$ such that $U$ is contained in $V$ and for all $z$ in $U$
$$F_1(z)=F_2(z)=f(z)$$
then
$$F_1=F_2$$
on all of $V$.

Answer (score 2):

Two simple classes of examples:

- Any sequence of positive numbers whose sum in one ordering diverges will diverge in every ordering
- Any sequence of numbers whose limit is not zero in one ordering will not have limit zero in any ordering, and thus forms a divergent sum

Comment: "ny sequence of positive numbers whose sum in one ordering diverges will diverge in every ordering", https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w-I6XTVZXww

Comment: @jimjim : That video does not demonstrate an ordering of the summands that produces a converging sum, so the video is not relevant to the line you quote.

Answer (score 1):

For series in $\mathbb{R}$ the situation is very clear: Let

$$ P = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n^{+} \quad \text{and} \quad N = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n^{-}, $$

where $a_n^+ = \max\{a_n, 0\}$ and $a_n^- = \max\{-a_n, 0\}$. Then

1. If $P < \infty$ and $N < \infty$, the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ is absolutely convergent.
2. If $P = \infty$ and $N < \infty$, then for any permutation $\sigma : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ we have $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{\sigma(n)} = \infty$.
3. If $P < \infty$ and $N = \infty$, then for any permutation $\sigma : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ we have $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{\sigma(n)} = -\infty$.
4. If $P = \infty$ and $N = \infty$, then there exist permutations $\sigma$ and $\tau$ on $\mathbb{N}$ such that both $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{\sigma(n)}$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{\tau(n)}$ exist in $[-\infty, \infty]$ but they do not equal: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{\sigma(n)} \neq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{\tau(n)}$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, from Riemann theorem such sequences exist. It is obvious that any such sequence is alternating. All positive sequences are absolutely con(div)ergent.

It is also obvious that necessary condition should still be true for it.
The condition is that both positive and negative terms are divergent. See: [If an infinite series is divergent, after rearrangement can it be convergent?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1221219/if-an-infinite-series-is-divergent-after-rearrangement-can-it-be-convergent?noredirect=1&lq=1)
As for "assign values to divergent series" that is called regularization and is not part of this classic summation rules. After all the simplest example is Zeta function! And that is complex analysis.